# Add QR code using external javascript file within Sencha framework

Tags: javascript, qr-code, extjs3

We are trying to add functionality to an old system. Our clients use scanners, so it would be ideal if we could add a QR code on screen for them to scan. I found a small open source javascript library that displays QR codes. I wanted to use that, but I am pulling the URL from the database, putting it into a Store, and then populating a link on screen. So, I have the following:

```
        this.searchForm = {
            frame: true,
            xtype: 'form',
            layout: 'form',
            labelWidth: 150,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'component',
                fieldLabel: 'Wireless App',
                tpl: '<div id="qrcode" style="width:100px; height:100px;"></div><a href="{Url}">{Url}</a>',
                data: { Url: '' },
                ref: '../../WirelessAppLabel'
            }, {
                xtype: 'label',
                ref:'../../StatusLabel'
            }]
        };

        lookupRF: function(search) {
            this.createRFLookup();
            this.lookupRFWindow.show();

            this.WirelessAppStore = WirelessAppUrl.getInstance().createStore();
            
            PM.Retriever.retrieve([this.WirelessAppStore], {
                callback: function (response, success) {
                    if (success) {
                        this.WMSAppUrl = this.WirelessAppStore.data.items[0].data.Url;

                        this.lookupRFWindow.WirelessAppLabel.update({ Url: this.WMSAppUrl });
                        new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), this.WMSAppUrl);
                    }
                },
                scope: this
            });
        }
```

where PM is a namespace we created internally. (These two functions are not in the same file, but one references the other). But, I keep getting errors saying QRCode is not defined. I tried loading it using Ext.Loader.load() and also just adding a reference to the script in index.html, but neither option worked. Any suggestions?

Here is the link to the QR Code javascript we are attempting to utilize: https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much easier approach. Rather than try to do everything in Javascript, it is already hitting the server to pull from the database, so I added a QR Code generator that created a Bitmap server side, which converts it into a Base64String. So, now my code looks like this:

```
    this.searchForm = {
        frame: true,
        xtype: 'form',
        layout: 'form',
        labelWidth: 150,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'component',
            fieldLabel: 'Wireless App',
            tpl: '<a href="{Url}">{Url}</a><br/><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {Image}" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />',
            data: {
                Url: '',
                Image: ''
            },
            ref: '../../WirelessAppLabel'
        }, {
            xtype: 'label',
            ref:'../../StatusLabel'
        }]
    };

    lookupRF: function(search) {
        this.createRFLookup();
        this.lookupRFWindow.show();

        this.WirelessAppStore = WirelessAppUrl.getInstance().createStore();
        
        PM.Retriever.retrieve([this.WirelessAppStore], {
            callback: function (response, success) {
                if (success) {
                    this.WMSAppUrl = this.WirelessAppStore.data.items[0].data.Url;
                    this.WMSAppImage = this.WirelessAppStore.data.items[0].data.QRCode;

                    this.lookupRFWindow.WirelessAppLabel.update({
                        Url: this.WMSAppUrl,
                        Image: this.WMSAppImage
                    });
                }
            },
            scope: this
        });
```

And then to actually create the QRCode, I used this open source package: https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder

Not exactly the solution that was asked for, but it works really well.